# Why SQL Server cut precision to 3 or 6 places

Tags: sql, sql-server, precision

I have a big problem with calculations in sql(sql server management studio)

I have a variable declare @KursEur decimal(32,10) = 4.2617000000

**I need 10 places after dot presicion**

I need the result of multiplying the values ​​from the database with a variable with 10 places after the dot precision

ColumnName = decimal(32,10)

examples:

```
select ColumnName*@KursEUR 
from TableName
```

Result: 364947858427.467456

```
 select ColumnName*4.2617000000 
 from TableName
```

Result: 364947858427.46745556204873 <-i need this result

I tried it but it doesn't give the expected result :

```
 select CAST(ColumnName as numeric(32,10))* CAST(@KursEUR as numeric(32,10)) 
 from TableName

select CAST(ColumnName as float)* CAST(@KursEUR as float) 
 from TableName

 select CAST(ColumnName  as numeric(32,10))* CAST(@KursEUR as float) 
 from TableName

 select CAST(ColumnName as float)* CAST(@KursEUR as numeric(32,10)) 
 from TableName

 select ColumnName* CAST(@KursEUR as float) 
 from TableName;
select ColumnName* CAST(@KursEUR as numeric(32,10)) 
 from TableName

select CAST(ColumnName as numeric(32,10))* @KursEUR 
 from TableName

select CAST(ColumnName as float)* @KursEUR
 from TableName

 select CAST(ColumnName*@KursEUR as float) 
 from TableName

 select CAST(ColumnName*@KursEUR as numeric(32,10)) 
 from TableName
```

Comment: The [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql) for how precision and scale are determined based on input precision and scale and operation are quite complicated, but they do explain your result. In all of this you've failed to state what the type of `ColumnName` is, though.

Comment: You might want to consider the documentation for [precision and scale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and especially the table that shows the result after multiplication.

Comment: ColumnName = decimal(32,10)

Comment: The *real* question here is, do you "*need"* a precision of 32? The largest number you can store with a `decimal(32,10)` is 9,999,999,999,999,999,999,999.9999999999; that's 10  Sextillion - 1... A truly *huge* number.

Comment: Well you can't multiply two `decimal(32, 10)` and maintain full precision, as that exceeds what SQL Server can support. How many digits does your input *actually* have? The usual solution to precision woes is to cut down on the precision (leaving the scale intact).

Comment: Besides, casting to a lower precision type like `float` *guarantees* loss of precision. `numeric` is still a floating-point number, with far greater precision than `float` but *still* susceptible to scaling errors `364947858427.467456` has a *very* different scale from `4.2617`.

Comment: i dont care about 32. I need 10 places after dot.

Comment: this is application for bank , they want (32,10)

Comment: Then use the lowest precision that works for your input. `SELECT 85634338040.5630277969 * 4.2617` yields `364947858427.46745556204873`; that's a `DECIMAL(21, 10)` multiplied by a `DECIMAL(5, 4)`.

Comment: *"i dont care about 32. I need 10 places after dot. "* Then why make the precision 32? If you don't *need* 22 digits *before* the decimal place, then don't declare your data type to state you *do*. Declare the data type to have an **appropriate** precision. If you need  (at most) 10 digits before the decimal point, and 10 after, for example, then you would use a `decimal(20,10)`.

Comment: Adding to that, your desired result has *14* decimal digits instead of 10. And what you see is the *formatted* number displayed by your client tool (SSMS is a client tool). If you specified more digits to display, eg with the `FORMAT` command, you may see the entire result. I'd still expect it to be `numeric(32,10)` though

Comment: `this is application for bank` and banks know all about rounding, which is why they use specific rounding strategies instead of depending on infinite precision decimals. This goes back at least to Superman 2. That's why eg XR conversions *require* a specific number of digits instead of arbitrary precision

Comment: Note that if your solution truly requires that *any* two `DECIMAL(32, 10)` numbers should be multipliabe without loss (which I sincerely doubt) then you simply can't use SQL Server, and would need to look at something like an arbitrary precision numerics library on the client end. This is seldom necessary, though; more typically people fail to appreciate that reducing the number of *total* digits ("precision") has positive effects for the number of digits available after the separator ("scale").

Comment: i change (32,10) to decimal(11,10) in @kursEur and its working!

Comment: So you don't need more than 1 digit prior to the decimal place?

Comment: 1? i dont understand. @KursEur is now(11,10)

Comment: I always think that decimal(11,10) means = 11111111111,2222222222

Comment: omg im so stupid, i understand now

Comment: 11 all digits, 10 after dot so (11,10) means 1,1111111111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you multiply two numbers in SQL Server, the product's precision is determined by adding the precision from both numbers together plus one. In your case, if both numbers have a precision of 32, then the resulting product would need a precision of 65! The max is 38 (or smaller on earlier versions)!!

The trick is to use smaller variable sizes. If you cast @KursEur as decimal(11,10). and cast the ColumnName as something like decimal(25,10) it will work. Balance the precision between the two numbers as your needs require, just make sure they add up to 37 or less.

```
SELECT CAST(85634338040.5630277969 AS DECIMAL(25,10)) * CAST(4.2617000000 AS DECIMAL(11,10))
```